# Entities Extraction and removal from String

Tags: java, string, extract, text-extraction

what I want to do is to extract sub-strings from a given string.

For example

```
String str = "Eminem - Not Afraid with lyrics 2010";
String str2 = "Eminem - Not Afraid (HQ)";
String str3 = " Eminem Not afraid (Lyrics)";
```

I want to remove the extra words like

```
lyrics
2010
HQ
()
with
```

If I have a hashtable contained all the "extra strings"

What's the best way to remove the extra strings from a given string?

I used regex at first but its not useful, also I used some entites extraction for artist name (echonest) but its only for artists

the problem will be if the song contains extra strings, the contained extra strings will be removed, too.

so please guys , any help or suggestion ?

thanks

Comment: why can't u just try str =str.replace(badStr, "") in a loop for all bad str?

Comment: what if I have with in the badStr and the song is "with you" :S

Answer (score 2):

Apache's StringUtils might be your friend here:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

It's a lot more versatile then the String/String utils that come with the JDK. (For example it has a "LastIndexOf" method that will help you in getting the last "with" in a string that has multiple "with").

Answer (score 1):

You could improve the performance but here is a solution to get you started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "Eminem - Not Afraid with lyrics 2010";
    String str2 = "Eminem - Not Afraid (HQ)";
    String str3 = " Eminem Not afraid (Lyrics)";

    System.out.println(replace(str));
    System.out.println(replace(str2));
    System.out.println(replace(str3));
}



private static String replace(String string) {
    List<String> extraList = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "lyrics", "2010", "HQ", "(", ")", "with" });
    for (String extra : extraList) {
        int index = string.indexOf(extra);
        while (index >= 0) {
            string = string.substring(0, index) + string.substring(index + extra.length(), string.length());
            index = string.indexOf(extra);
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

Note that "indexOf" is case sensitive, if you want to ignore case you will have to write your own another String utility library.  Note the "toUpperCase" and "toLowerCase" string methods which might come in handy for you.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks , but what do you think should I do if I have song like this
Chris Brown - With You

thanks again for the help :)

Comment: The problem with this solution is it still doesn't cater for the case where the word "lyrics" might be in the song title, which the OP specifically wants to avoid removing. Any method that manipulates the string is going to have to take the title in to ensure it doesn't eliminate words from it.

Comment: Yes Mark is correct.  You need to identify the actual titles, which in a real world scenario is probably going to be really hard.  What is it exactly that you are trying to do?  Are you trying to end up with every song tagged "Eminem - Not Afraid"?  Or are you trying to somehow identify that "Eminem - Not Afraid", "Eminem not afraid" and "Eminem, not afraid" are all the same title and leave these sections untouched?  Do you have a list of all legitimate song titles?  Is your data clean?  Give us more please.

Comment: I am getting the information by the title using several api's including last.fm , so if I sent the wrong title it will show different information

Comment: sorry if I misunderstand.  It seems like you are telling me why it is important that you clean the title (so you can use it to look up other information), but I'm asking HOW you expect to clean the title.  How would you possibly recognize whether the string "with" was part of the title or not?  Do you have a list of legitimate titles?  Do you expect that your initial data (the stuff you are cleaning) will be formatted to match your list, or is it full of commas and dashes and misspellings etc?

Comment: I'm afraid the likely answer is that for a real-world application, the data cleaning is going to be a huge value add for your product and not something that will be trivially answered in this kind of format.  It's going to be an extremely hard problem.  Sorry.